# Check integrity of label on trainingdata

Tags: python, dataframe

I have machine learning excel file (>30k rows, 845 columns) and would like to check a column value (the training value). If a different training value is assigned to same attributes columns 12 - 849 it would mess up the machine learning.

Since a dictionary can only have 1 key and I would like to have multiple entries with the same training value assignment it is not an option.

What are efficient options iterating through such a big file, check for wrong entries and color code the wrong assignments (different name with same attributes)?

Table looks like this:

[columns before are info-columns, columns after are till 840 similar, after that info-columns again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm5WZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Having sample as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5], 
     'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'c', 'e' ], 
     'label': ['1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image]

And assuming that you want:

- detect as the incorrect case rows 4 and 7 as those have the same values in col1 and col2 but different labels
- detect as the correct case rows 2 and 6 because those have the same values in col1, col2 and label
- detect as the correct cases remining rows because those have the different values in col1, col2 and label

I will suggest to:

Group by columns 0:2 (in your case 12:850) and create the set of the labels (only unique values will appear):

```
aggregated = df.groupby(list(df.columns[0:2]))['label'].apply(set).reset_index(name='label')
aggregated
```

[image]

and filter out for cases where set size is greater than one:

```
aggregated[aggregated.label.str.len() > 1]
```

[image]

Comment: I got the error message: "dataframe is highly fragmented. this is usually the result of calling frame.insert many times" So I needed to merge the +800 columns with the attrubutes to compare "DF_DATA["attributes"] = DF_DATA[DF_DATA.columns[11:840]].apply(lambda x: ",".join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)". My new dataframe with the aggregated data is now missing the initial indeces. Do you have a solution to find the initial entries in the excel (csv) sheet?